# Print Username in print composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, expression

Is it possible to use any expression to get the username of machine/computer and path of project while printing the documents in print composer of QGIS.

Comment: Did you look at the variable list in the expression editor?

Comment: [% @project_author %] will give you the computer name

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton ... I found the solution under "Variable"

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz ...